# present continuous for a future plan that is only involving you

Tags: present-tense, continuous

Can we use present continuous for a future event even it involves only yourself 
If you are a student can you say I am working tomorrow or is it better to say  I am going to work tomorrow as only  the person working is involved

Answer (score 2):

The number of people involved is not relevant. You can say "I am working tomorrow", "I am going to France in January", "I am visiting my mother on Saturday", etc.